# Are uncountable roots of polynomials with measurable coefficients measurable?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, algebraic-geometry

There's a similar question asked before here: [roots of polynomial with measurable coefficients](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1391280/roots-of-polynomial-with-measurable-coefficients/1391890), but with finite roots.

If I have random multivariate polynomial:

$$f=\sum_\alpha a_\alpha x^\alpha, \quad \alpha=(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n) \text{ is a tuple of nonnegative integers}$$

$a_\alpha(\omega):\Omega\to\mathbb R^n$ are measurable functions

Assume that for every $\omega$ (fixed coefficient) there are possibly **uncountably infinite** real roots to the polynomial. $f: \Omega\times \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with finite terms and bounded degree.

Are these roots measurable functions wrt $\omega$? i.e., define the zeros as $\bar{x}(\omega)$, is $\{\omega:\bar{x}(\omega) \cap K\neq  \varnothing\}$ measurable wrt to $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$ for each $K$ compact?

($\bar{x}$ is measurable wrt to the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on the collection of closed sets $\mathcal{F}$ with respect to the Fell topology)

Basically, I'm trying to show the set of real roots is a random closed set if $\Omega$ is a probability space.

my attempt:

I was trying to prove measurability by continuity of mapping: $g: a_\alpha \mapsto \{x: f(x)=0\}$, only to find that part is even harder (not even true when cross boundaries of topological components).

It would be my best hope to have some help in the proof. Any references would also be great!
Thank you

Comment: A polynomial with fixed coefficients has only finitely many roots?

Comment: I'm working with molynomials, multivariate polynomial

Comment: Ah, I never heard of "molynomials". That term is not standard in algebraic geometry, and seems to appear more often in probability contexts. Are you sure it does not refer to the "measurable" coefficients instead of the "multivariate" nature? But nomenclature aside, do you have infinitely many $a_\alpha$ or is the degree bounded?

Comment: Yes, finite many $a_\alpha$ and bounded degree, question edited.

Comment: Say $d$ is the upper bound for you degree, and denote the polynomials of degree $\leq d$ by $\mathbb R[x_1, \dotsc, x_n]_{\leq d}$. Then you have a continuous evaluation map $\mathbb R[x_1, \dotsc, x_n]_{\leq d} \times \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R, (p, x) \mapsto p(x)$. Maybe combine this with your measurable map $f: \Omega \to \mathbb R[x_1, \dotsc, x_n]_{\leq d}$?

Comment: I would say that's the hard part? Sorry I dont quite get how to show the measurability of the evaluation map wrt to $\mathbb{R}[x_1,\dots,x_n]_{\leq d}$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139615/discussion-between-kyle-and-red-trumpet).